# ipfs.name.publish command in js-ipfs not working, throwing error

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

I am working with js-ipfs and want to use the publish functionality of IPFS.
Given below is the code

```
let result = await ipfs.add("hello");

const ipns_hash = await ipfs.name.publish('/ipfs/'+result.cid)
console.log(ipns_hash)
```

I referred the offcial js-ipfs CORE APIs documentation for the implementation of the [publish](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/NAME.md#ipfsnamepublishvalue-options) command above.

This is the error I get when I run the above command,

```
file:///home/shubh/Desktop/BTech/Project/ipfstrail/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/esm/src/lib/core.js:75
            let error = new HTTP.HTTPError(response);
                        ^
          
          **HTTPError: ipns record for f5uxa3ttf4acicabciqiyeamon3gnuvgikdcknbuwyhicyeolhegmomtrvd5fpy53oulfvy could not be stored in the routing**

              at Object.errorHandler [as handleError] (file:///home/shubh/Desktop/BTech/Project/ipfstrail/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/esm/src/lib/core.js:75:15)
              at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
              at async Client.fetch (/home/shubh/Desktop/BTech/Project/ipfstrail/node_modules/ipfs-utils/src/http.js:145:9)
              at async Object.publish (file:///home/shubh/Desktop/BTech/Project/ipfstrail/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/esm/src/name/publish.js:6:17)
              at async saveText (file:///home/shubh/Desktop/BTech/Project/ipfstrail/app.js:156:23) {
            response: Response {
              size: 0,
              timeout: 0,
              [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
                body: PassThrough {
                  _readableState: ReadableState {
                    objectMode: false,
                    highWaterMark: 16384,
                    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
                    length: 0,
                    pipes: [],
                    flowing: true,
                    ended: true,
                    endEmitted: true,
                    reading: false,
                    constructed: true,
                    sync: false,
                    needReadable: false,
                    emittedReadable: false,
                    readableListening: false,
                    resumeScheduled: false,
                    errorEmitted: false,
                    emitClose: true,
                    autoDestroy: true,
                    destroyed: true,
                    errored: null,
                    closed: true,
                    closeEmitted: true,
                    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
                    awaitDrainWriters: null,
                    multiAwaitDrain: false,
                    readingMore: false,
                    dataEmitted: true,
                    decoder: null,
                    encoding: null,
                    [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
                  },
                  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
                    prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
                    error: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ],
                    data: [Function (anonymous)],
                    end: [Function (anonymous)]
                  },
                  _eventsCount: 4,
                  _maxListeners: undefined,
                  _writableState: WritableState {
                    objectMode: false,
                    highWaterMark: 16384,
                    finalCalled: true,
                    needDrain: false,
                    ending: true,
                    ended: true,
                    finished: true,
                    destroyed: true,
                    decodeStrings: true,
                    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
                    length: 0,
                    writing: false,
                    corked: 0,
                    sync: false,
                    bufferProcessing: false,
                    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
                    writecb: null,
                    writelen: 0,
                    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
                    buffered: [],
                    bufferedIndex: 0,
                    allBuffers: true,
                    allNoop: true,
                    pendingcb: 0,
                    constructed: true,
                    prefinished: true,
                    errorEmitted: false,
                    emitClose: true,
                    autoDestroy: true,
                    errored: null,
                    closed: true,
                    closeEmitted: true,
                    [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
                  },
                  allowHalfOpen: true,
                  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
                  [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
                },
                disturbed: true,
                error: null
              },
              [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
                url: 'http://localhost:5002/api/v0/name/publish?arg=%2Fipfs%2FQmWfVY9y3xjsixTgbd9AorQxH7VtMpzfx2HaWtsoUYecaX',
                status: 500,
                statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
                headers: Headers {
                  [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
                    'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
                    'cache-control': [ 'no-cache' ],
                    'content-length': [ '160' ],
                    date: [ 'Tue, 22 Feb 2022 17:42:43 GMT' ],
                    connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
                    'keep-alive': [ 'timeout=5' ]
                  }
                },
                counter: 0
              }
            }
          }
```

Is there any solution around this?

Note: I am working on ipfs-http-client module of version ^55.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm a rookie on this too. But if you are using "jsipfs daemon" then that can be a problem as well. I used the IPFS Desktop and the credentials(Like, gateway and API) on that. That fixed my issue.

Unlike you, I'm creating a directory separately, and then I wrote my files into that folder. Like below.

```
const createdir = async () => {
  await ipfs.files.mkdir("/test")
  const data = await ipfs.files.stat('/test')
  return;
}
const publish = async () => {
  const key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  const buffered = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ content:"some content on the json", key }))
  await ipfs.files.write(`/test/${key}.json`, buffered, { create: true });
  const folder = await ipfs.files.stat('/test')
  const address = folder.cid._baseCache.get("z");
  const res = await ipfs.name.publish("/ipfs/" + address)
}
```

And I'm using
"**ipfs-http-client**": "**^56.0.3**", seems, the latest version have issues..
"**js-ipfs**": "**^0.13.5**"

Hope it helped.